# Ошибка при выводе узора

Tags: python

Пытаюсь создать программу, которая выводит узор из символов.

```
pattern = ["*|*A|A*|*", "V/\V"]
numCombination = [0]
count = 7
i = 0
a = 1
patternPart = " "
while a < 5:
    inputNumber = input("Enter the number from 0 to 1:")
    numCombination.append(inputNumber)
    a = a + 1
while i < count:
    numComb = numCombination[i]
    patternPart = patternPart + pattern[arrayComb]
    i = i + 1
print(patternPart)
```

Но выводит такую ошибку:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-52c3607388cd> in <module>
     11 while i < count:
     12     numComb = numCombination[i]
---> 13     patternPart = patternPart + pattern[arrayComb]
     14     i = i + 1
     15 print(patternPart)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Пробовал вывести переменную arrayComb за цикл while, но тогда выводится только первый узор из list.
P.s. Писал код в Anaconda Notebook
P.P.s Только начал изучать Python

Comment: Переименуйте переменную `list` и не используйте название типов в качестве идентификаторов переменных.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда обновлю код и ошибку  в вопросе

Comment: а откуда берётся arrayComb со строкой внутри ? pattern[arrayComb]

Comment: @Интик, это опечатка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

индекс должен быть числом а не строкой, поэтому надо `input` переводить в число

```
int(input("Enter the number from 0 to 1:"))
```

И `while a < 5:` лучше заменить на `while a < count:`

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял как сделать)